# Angular service returning undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I've got a function in an Angular controller like so:

```
app.controller("UsersController", ["$scope",  "UserList", function($scope, UserList) {

    $scope.createUserSubmit = function(newUser) {

      UserList.createUser().success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });

    }

}]);
```

When the `createUserSubmit()` function is called, it calls another function to a function `createUser()` in a service `UserList`.

The service looks like this:

```
app.service("UserList", function() {
  this.createUser = function(){
    console.log("doing it");
    return "hi";
  }
});
```

Now, when this all runs, I get the "doing it" message logged, but then I get the following error and the `console.log(data)` does not log.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Normally this type of error would be self explanatory, so either I'm being a moron or there's something confusing going on. As far as I can see, it is a function.

Comment: `.success` does not become available automatically from any return value, you need to return angular httpPromise for that

Comment: @PSL Thanks. This code above is abbreviated, but there's actually an http call to a database in the `createUser()` function. I then return the data from that call. If I can't do `.success`, how can I do a callback with the returned data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not get `success` method from a string return value (which you are returning from your method `createUser`). You get it as a part of angular `$http`'s [httpPromise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage). If you are actually doing an ajax call with http just return `$http` call.

```
app.service("UserList", function($http) {
  this.createUser = function(){
    return $http('...');
  }
});
```

`success` and `error` methods are special function added to httpPromise inaddition to $q promise functions, it is an extension to `$q` promise.

And if you are looking to return data return a `$q` promise, which has a `then` method which is equivalent to `success` method. $q promise does not have `success` and `error` methods.

```
app.service("UserList", function($http) {
  this.createUser = function(){
    return $http('...').then(function(response){ 
             //Do your transformation and return the data
             return response.data;
           });
  }
});
```

and

```
UserList.createUser().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```